# Spring IMAP Poller reads emails after some hours of delay

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-integration, jakarta-mail, imap

I am using Spring Integration to poll emails from **3 mailboxes using 3 adapters.**
I am using **customSearchTermStatregy** to read emails after 10 mins of receiving.

This application reads email and saving those email into **local directory as .eml file**.

Now the problem is, some email are read **after 4-5 hours of delay** by the poller.

I configured a thread pool as well, but I suspect spring poller is **not getting thread allocated** immediately to read email, hence the delay in reading.

Please also note, this application is running under tomcat **along with other 10+ java applications** running under same tomcat.

Can someone point out **some probable reasons** behind this 4-5 hours of delay?

**Spring Integration.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"       
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail-5.2.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd">

    <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
        <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
        <prop key="mail.debug">${imap.debug}</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imaps.partialfetch">false</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imaps.fetchsize">102400</prop>   <!-- 100KB, default is 16KB -->  
    </util:properties>
    
    <task:executor id="taskExecutor"  pool-size="15-50" queue-capacity="100"/>

    <mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter1" 
                                      store-uri="${imap.uri.mail}"                                     
                                      channel="recieveEmailChannel"                                          
                                      should-delete-messages="false"
                                      should-mark-messages-as-read="true"                                      
                                      auto-startup="true"
                                      simple-content="true"
                                      auto-close-folder="false"
                                      search-term-strategy="mailSearchTermStrategy"
                                      java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
       <!-- <int:poller fixed-delay="${imap.polling.interval}" time-unit="SECONDS"/> -->
       <int:poller cron="0 0/2 1-23 * * ?" max-messages-per-poll="1" task-executor="taskExecutor"/> <!-- every 2 mins, from 1AM to 11.59PM -->
    </mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
    
    <mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter2" 
                                      store-uri="${imap.uri.fax}"                                     
                                      channel="recieveEmailChannel"                                          
                                      should-delete-messages="false"
                                      should-mark-messages-as-read="true"                                      
                                      auto-startup="true"
                                      simple-content="true"
                                      auto-close-folder="false"
                                      search-term-strategy="faxSearchTermStrategy"
                                      java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
       <int:poller cron="0 0/2 1-23 * * ?" max-messages-per-poll="1" task-executor="taskExecutor"/> <!-- every 2 mins, from 1AM to 11.59PM -->
    </mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
    
    <mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter3" 
                                      store-uri="${imap.uri.scan}"                                     
                                      channel="recieveEmailChannel"                                          
                                      should-delete-messages="false"
                                      should-mark-messages-as-read="true"                                      
                                      auto-startup="true"
                                      simple-content="true"
                                      auto-close-folder="false"
                                      search-term-strategy="scanSearchTermStrategy"
                                      java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
      <int:poller cron="0 0/2 1-23 * * ?" max-messages-per-poll="1" task-executor="taskExecutor"/> <!-- every 2 mins, from 1AM to 11.59PM -->
     </mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="recieveEmailChannel">        
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="DEBUG"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="recieveEmailChannel" ref="emailReceiver" method="handleMessage"/>

  <!-- <bean id="emailReceiver" class="com.abc.xyz.receiver.EmailReceiver">
    </bean>  -->  
</beans>
```

**CustomSearchTermStrategy:**

```
@Service
public class CustomSearchTermStrategy implements SearchTermStrategy {
    
    @Value("${email.delay.mins}")
    int emailDelayMins; 
    
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomSearchTermStrategy.class);
    
    @Override
    public SearchTerm generateSearchTerm(Flags supportedFlags, Folder folder) {
        
         SearchTerm customSentDateTerm = new SearchTerm(){           
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 4583016738325920713L;

            public boolean match(Message message) {
                 try {
                     ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");                  
                     ZonedDateTime sendDtInPST =  message.getSentDate().toInstant().atZone(zoneId);              
                     ZonedDateTime currentZdt = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);                  
                     ZonedDateTime currentTimeMinus10Mins = currentZdt.minusMinutes(emailDelayMins);
                     Flags flags = message.getFlags();
 
                     if(currentTimeMinus10Mins.isAfter(sendDtInPST)) {                       
                        if(!flags.contains(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {
                         logger.info("CurrentTimeMinus"+emailDelayMins+"MinsInPST is AFTER sendDtInPST, so this email picked for read, subject:{}", message.getSubject());
                         return true;   
                        }
                     }   
                 } catch (Exception ex) {
                     ex.printStackTrace();
                  }
                 return false;
             }
         };
        return customSentDateTerm;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In our case, the delay in polling a large email from the IMAP server was because we used default values for properties mail.imap.fetchsize=16kb and mail.imap.partialfetch=true.

This made the email to be fetched in sizes of 16kb which resulted in long hours for polling. So we set the mail.imap.partialfetch=false to ensure that the mail gets fetched at a stretch

Refer this https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html for further property setting in IMAP

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you show 3 pollers which are going to be run at the same time.
By default all those pollers are triggered by the `TaskScheduler` (don't mix it with `TaskExecutor`), which is based on 10 threads pool. So, even right now I see 3 concurrent threads taken by your email channel adapters. It might not be a surprise that you have some other pollers in your your applications. And all of them share the same `TaskScheduler`.

You may revise all your pollers to shift the real work into particular executors, or you may consider to increase the `TaskScheduler` thread pool: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler

You also can do a thread dump to analyze which threads are busy and for what.

Comment: Thanks @Artem, I have only 3 pollers, Along with TaskExecutor, I will configure TaskScheduler also as advised. Do you think of any other reason other than thread starvation for this delay in polling?